# Function with Future return type always returns None

Tags: scala, playframework

I have the following functions:

```
//retrieves record from database
def getAll: Future[List[User]] = {
  try {
    Logger.info("Getting all user record.")
    db.run(userTableQuery.to[List].result)
  }
  catch {
    case ex: Exception => Logger.error("Exception in getting all user record. " + ex)
      Future {
        List[User]()
      }
  }
}


//checks whethe the email exist in list or not
def checkEmail(email : String): Future[Option[User]] ={
  /* userRepo.getAll.map(userList => userList.filter(user => user.email == email).map { value => println(value)
     userList
   })*/
  userRepo.getAll.map(userList => userList.filter(user => user.email == email).headOption)

}


//allows to sign in and redirects to dashboard
def signIn() = {
  Logger.debug("signingIn in progress. ")
  loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      Logger.error("Sign-In badRequest.")
      Future(BadRequest(views.html.home(webJarAssets, formWithErrors, signUpForm)))
    },
    validData => {
      userService.checkEmail(validData.email).map(value => {
        value match {
          case Some(us) =>Redirect(routes.HomeController.homePage).flashing("ERROR" -> "User  exist")
          case None => Redirect(routes.HomeController.homePage).flashing("ERROR" -> "User doesn't exist")
        }
      }
      )
    }
  )
}
```

But when I call `signin()` it always returns `None`.

I used some debugger code and I guess `filter()` inside `checkMail()` is not working properly.
However `getall()` working properly and gives all the record in database.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: What is userRepo.getAll returning? Is userRepo an instance of the class whose function you're showing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in how you compare the user email with the provided one inside the filter in the checkMail() function.
Strings equality is a bit tricky, if you compare them using == you are comparing the objects and not the values so you should use .equals() to compare the values.
You can read more on this [blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml)

Try to rewrite checkMail() like this:

```
  def checkEmail(email : String): Future[Option[User]] ={
      userRepo.getAll.map(userList => userList.filter(user => user.email.equals( email ) ).headOption)
  }
```

You can also simplify .filter() e .headOption using find(), it does the same thing only in one command. You can rewrite it like this:

```
  def checkEmail(email : String): Future[Option[User]] ={
      userRepo.getAll.map(userList => userList.find(user => user.email.equals( email ) ) )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using filter you may use find method under checkmail. And also, since this is scala you are using "==" correctly, please see blog [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-compare-strings-with-equal-operator-method-not-equals)

I hope this code would fix:

```
//checks whethe the email exist in list or not
def checkEmail(email : String): Future[Option[User]] ={
  /* userRepo.getAll.map(userList => userList.filter(user => user.email == email).map { value => println(value)
     userList
   })*/
  userRepo.getAll.map(userList => userList.find(user => user.email == email))

}
```

I tried to simulate/experiment regarding your implementation in direct way using the terminal:

```
scala> case class User(email: String)
defined class User

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val allUser = scala.concurrent.Future {List(User("carl@test.com"), User("los@test.com"), User("pos@test.com"))}
allUser: scala.concurrent.Future[List[User]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@751d3241

scala> val checkmail = allUser.map(userlist=>userlist.find(user=>user.email == "carl@test.com"))
checkmail: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[User]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@1358b28e

scala> val rslt = checkmail.map(value => value match {case Some(x) =>println(x); x.email case None => println("None"); "nothing" })
rslt: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@18324f97
User(carl@test.com)

scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._


scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> Await.result(rslt, 3 seconds)
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res8: String = carl@test.com
```